# push nested array comments with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, comments, push

I get a array like this for comments from server :

```
var comments = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1]
}, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1]
}, {
    id: 5,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1, 3]
}, {
    id: 6,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}];
```

The parent array on each object are the address of it's parent and above that.
So i want to push each comment to correct parent in new reply array item.
I'm sorted comments with this way :

```
var sort = function(a, b) {
    if (a.pasokh.length < b.pasokh.length) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.pasokh.length > b.pasokh.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
};

comments.sort(sort);
```

Then getting array like this :

```
[{
    id: 5,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1, 3]
}, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1]
}, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [1]
}, {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}, {
    id: 6,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}]
```

The order of the comments might be not be exactly correct like above.
what the best way to push `id:5` to `id:3` and id:3 & id:4`to`id:1` and get the array like this :

```
[{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: [],
    reply: [{
        id: 3,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
        parent: [1],
        reply: [{
            id: 5,
            text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
            parent: [1, 3]
        }, ]
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
        parent: [1]
    }, ]
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}, {
    id: 6,
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ',
    parent: []
}]
```

Comment: do you like to get the last one, the tree?

Comment: yes, I want to create the last array from the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal works for unsorted data. It take `id` as reference and applys even for not known `id` an object to the temp object, and fill it later with the given data. That means this solution does only require one loop.

```js
var comments = [{ id: 1, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [] }, { id: 2, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [] }, { id: 3, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [1] }, { id: 4, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [1] }, { id: 5, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [1, 3] }, { id: 6, text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ', parent: [] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var r = [],
            o = Object.create(null);

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var id;
            a.reply = o[a.id] && o[a.id].reply;
            o[a.id] = a;
            id = a.parent.reduce(function (r, a) {
                r !== null && !(a in o) && o[r].reply.push(o[a] = {});
                return a;
            }, null);
            if (id !== null) {
                o[id].reply = o[id].reply || [];
                o[id].reply.push(a);
            } else {
                r.push(o[a.id]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(comments);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: something mockery happen's when run this snippet on chrome it's include `id:5` in both of reply `id:1` and `id:3` which should be include only in `id:3`

Comment: in facet in chrome the code include item in parent and another forefathers

Comment: @SydAmir, it was a unmotivated push, please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Sort Array with minimum length of parent.
- Then loop over `.parent` and search necessary object recursively. For more than 1 parent, set `searchNode` as reply of previous parent.
- Once the loop is over, push current object in it.

```js
var comments=[{id:1,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[]},{id:2,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[]},{id:3,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[1]},{id:4,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[1]},{id:5,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[1,3]},{id:6,text:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ",parent:[]}];

var r = [];
comments.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.parent.length - b.parent.length
}).forEach(function(o) {
  if (o.parent.length > 0) {
    var lastNode = comments;
    o.parent.forEach(function(n) {
      if (!Array.isArray(lastNode)) lastNode = lastNode.reply
      lastNode = lastNode.find(x => x.id === n)
    });
    if (lastNode) {
      lastNode.reply = lastNode.reply || [];
      lastNode.reply.push(o)
    }
  } else {
    o.reply = [];
    r.push(o);
  }
});

console.log(r)
```